# Routing Reactjs in Electron app

Tags: reactjs, routes, electron

I create applications Electron , the browser is ok but the environment Electron disagree route routing . In Annex I send the whole screen . Please advice.
[image: code and electron app]

Comment: What version of react-router is that? I had same problem on 2.0.1. The way I bypassed it was using hash history. You are not targeting any SEO tools anyway.

Comment: were you able to resolve this problem? I am also having this problem and solution give below is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've found to do this, with minimal effort was to use [path.join](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2), It's really helpful you know?

```
# IMPORT PATH ES6/7

# es6: const path = require('path');

# CONSTRUCT YOUR BUILD PATH
const build_path = path.join(__dirname), '/build');

# mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + build_path + '/index.html')

console.log('file://' + build_path + '/index.html');
# -> file://build/index.html
```